# DevExpress Xtrareports using a Business object as a datasource

Tags: asp.net, reporting, objectdatasource, business-objects

I am trying out DevExpress Xtrareports, but have asimple problem that I am not able to find an answer to.

In an Asp.net website project, I want to add a business object to my report as a datasource and then drag and drop the fields from my new business object data source onto the report designer.

Can some one help explain how i do this.

I asssume I have just missed something.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to give the designer a DataSet with one or more DataTables representing your business object. You would of course have to write some code to convert your business object to the data table and back.

As a side note DevExpress have a really good support forum and I have always gotten answers to my questions regarding their products. I recommend you try your question there unless you get a really good answer.